# Мы вознаграждаем авторов вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, репутация

*Текст ниже — перевод статьи «[We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/)», опубликованной Сарой Чиппс (Sara Chipps) в корпоративном блоге Stack Overflow. Оригинал распространяется по лицензии СС BY-SA 4.0.*

*Если кратко — с 14 ноября 2019 года голоса «за» приносят авторам вопросов не `5` баллов репутации как раньше, а `10`. Вес голосов «против» не изменился и по-прежнему составляет `-2` баллa.*

---

В [своей первой публикации](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/) я писала о личном опыте изучения сообщества Stack Overflow. Я упомянула, что мы планируем сделать шаг назад и пересмотреть процесс предоставления обратной связи: как мы можем улучшить качество содержимого сайта и как можно уменьшить трения между людьми. Также я отметила, что наша цель — сделать процесс создания вопросов безболезненным и полезным как для новичков, так и для ветеранов Stack Overflow.

В ходе этой переоценки мы заметили в системе репутации один момент: мы даём авторам ответов по `10` баллов репутации за каждый голос «за» на их ответах, но авторам вопросов лишь `5`.

Вот как всё начиналось: в 2008, на запуске Stack Overflow, мы давали одинаковое количество баллов как за вопросы, так и за ответы. 3 года спустя было принято решение удешевить плюсы за вопросы. Основанием стало побуждение сфокусировать участников на написание качественных ответов вместо создания вопросов.

Посмотрим теперь на это решение с учётом накопившегося опыта. На тот момент оно, наверное, и было верным, учитывая знания тех времён, но сейчас мы можем оценить последствия того решения. Награда за хороший ответ была выше награды за вопрос.

Как старый участник сообщества Stack Overflow я, как и все вы, знаю, что составить хороший вопрос сложно. Для этого требуется вдумчивость и внимание к тому, *как* лучше всего подать имеющуюся проблему. Надо сделать шаг назад и представить, будто вы описываете проблему случайному прохожему, не имеющему ни малейшего понятия о ситуации вокруг вашей проблемы. Этот прохожий не видел ваших логов, не знает вашей конечной цели, не в курсе ни об используемых библиотеках, ни о версии установленного у вас фреймворка.

Также не стоит забывать о том, что большая часть деталей при этом избыточна. Надо понимать, какие части сообщения об ошибке надо включать в вопрос, и что в нём применимо именно к вашему компьютеру. Надо выделить уже проделанные шаги и результаты исследований. Иными словами, для получения качественного ответа надо быть экспертом по части создания вопросов. Для этого требуется навык и опыт; это дорогого стоит, и это то, что мы хотим чествовать.

Сегодня всё возвращается на круги своя. Мы изменяем количество репутации, зарабатываемой за плюсы к вопросам, обратно на `10` баллов, приравнивая её к репутации, получаемой за плюсы на ответах.

Также репутация каждого участника Stack Overflow и Stack Exchange была пересчитана с учётом этого изменения. Каждый заработанный в прошлом плюс за вопрос теперь задним числом приносит на `5` баллов больше репутации.

Мы ожидаем, что дополнительную репутацию получит около 2,4 миллиона людей. Это изменение не только про репутацию; мы хотим донести мысль о том, что мы чествуем вопрошающих. Ура задающим вопросы!

Для тех, кто получит при этом новые привилегии: мы просим пользоваться полученной ответственностью обдуманно. Вы эксперты по написанию вопросов. Вы — люди, которые могут определить вопрос, вызывающий затруднения, и знаете все сложности этого процесса. Заранее спасибо вам за наставничество новичкам в области составления вопросов.

Мы верим, что и авторы вопросов, и отвечающие — важные части нашей экосистемы. Мы ценим то, как много они сделали для обустройства крупнейшей базы знаний технических вопросов и ответов в истории, и мы хотим поблагодарить их за каждый факт вклада, начиная с момента зарождения сайта.

Но мы не останавливаемся на этом.

Мы внедрили улучшенный процесс задания вопросов по всему Stack Overflow (сеть Stack Exchange, вы получите это обновление в первом квартале следующего года). Меган Рисдал [рассказала об улучшениях](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/upcoming-on-stack-overflow/) в августе, а Лиза Парк [поведала](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/) об исследовании, которое легло в их основу. И когда пришло время их применения, мы были взволнованы как никогда.

Вчера Юлия Силге [подвела итоги](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/) по результатам A/B-тестирования этого процесса. Мы увидели колоссальный прирост числа людей, опубликовавших вопросы. Мы обратили внимание и на качество этих вопросов, потому что мы хотим помочь людям писать вопросы, на которые с большой вероятностью будет дан ответ. Ухудшения в их качестве замечено не было.
*От переводчика: в [оригинальной статье](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/) было сказано, что качество всё-таки упало на `1.5%` в самом начале эксперимента, о чём говорят графики. Но вроде как на втором шаге эксперимента это ухудшение качества было нивелировано.*

Подытожим: это изменение увеличило количество вопросов, публикуемых на Stack Overflow, при этом с небольшим ущербом качеству. Больше высококачественных вопросов, — это путь к сообществу, в котором каждый процветает.

Я уже об этом писала, но напишу ещё раз. И я, и всё подразделение, ответственное за сообщества, безмерно рады улучшать процессы, касающиеся на Stack Overflow программистов всех уровней, от новичков, изучающих фронтенд впервые в жизни, до уважаемых модераторов, пишущих код уже более двадцати лет. Эти изменения, — увеличение баллов, начисляемых за вопросы и улучшенный процесс по созданию вопросов, — вкупе с новыми механизмами обратной связи, о которые мы объявим на следующей неделе, закладывают основы для начала работы рука об руку с сообществом для построения лучшего Stack Overflow.

Comment: Вот когда задаёшь хороший вопрос, назначаешь за него награду... Никто на него не отвечает. Спустя какое то время отвечаешь сам, а награда не возвращается... ИМХО это не честно!

Comment: Походил по профилям участников, которые получили резкое изменение репутации и нигде не увидел резкой свечки вверх. ([Например](https://stackexchange.com/users/5321360/iluxa1810?tab=reputation)) Выходит, это именно был пересчёт, когда не разово прибавили всем, а в каждый момент времени заменили старые оценки новыми.

Comment: @AK всё старое прогнали. Всё заменили. Все баджи пересчитали. К примеру, [легенду](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary).

Comment: Я от этого решения, получил +750 к репе, но я с таким решением не согласен, потому что ответ стоит на много дороже хорошего вопроса. Ибо типичный отвечальщик вместо того, чтобы заниматься своими проблемами идёт помогать коллегам, которые попали в беду. Напротив, тот  кто задаёт вопрос, пытается за счёт других выехать из своего болота. Так что, свои +750 к репе я бы с удовольствием отдал тем, кто помогли мне справится с моими проблемами.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, если прям хотите очистить свою совесть, можете раздать репутацию через [конкурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) (синяя ссылка "начать конкурс" под вопросом).

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Теперь у меня есть ещё один наглядный пример для CQRS EventSoursing, когда просто хранится лог действий и текущее состояние можно в любой момент времени пересчитать заново. Но [полтора терабайта оперативки](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1194719400349306880), боже мой...

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev дело не в совести. Я боюсь, что это кончится тем, что квалифицированные специалисты будут с меньшим энтузиазмом отвечать на вопросы.

Comment: @AK MS SQL. Хотя, есть вероятно, что там с архитектурой проблемы (¬‿¬). Такое ощущение, что они всё на одной ноде хранят, без партицирования и шардирования.

Comment: Вот честно, это полный бред. Они просто хотят отвлечь юзеров от Моники, кучи ушедших модераторов и дать им повосхищаться своими привилигиями и репутацией.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, _"отвечаешь сам, а награда не возвращается... ИМХО это не честно! "_ если бы награда возвращалась, это был бы эксплойт.

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica инициатива задолго до ситуации с Моникой родилась.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica я сначала почему-то решил, что речь об увеличении репутации за ответы :)

Comment: @i-one эксплойт? Вы уверены?  В чём же он заключается? Ответ автора вопроса единственный, что тут сложного и в чём эксплойт, поясните?

Comment: Ух... из не от куда получил +10к =DDD

Comment: @ Ver Nick says Reinstate Monica
а что за ситуация с Моникой? Может быть вы про Монику Левински? Так это 20 лет назад было. Уже три президента сменилось.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, [Моника Челлио](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102), бывший модератор кучи сайтов, отстранённый от должности 1) с грубейшим нарушением порядка отстранения модераторов, 2) за "нарушение" новой редакции Code of Conduct, которая на тот момент не только ещё не вступила в силу, но даже не была опубликована, 3) с отягчающими в виде случаев нарушения этой редакции в прошлом (то есть правила, оказывается, имеют обратную силу).

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, кто-то может разместить вопрос низкого качества, назначить конкурс. Не получив ответа, ответить самому себе что угодно (да хоть "абырвалг"), принять свой ответ и получить вознаграждение обратно. Потом отменить принятие ответа, удалить ответ, и снова можно назначать конкурс на этот же вопрос. Бесплатно фактически.

Comment: @i-one а модераторы и голосовалки на что? :) И в чем отличие от той же модели поведения без конкурса?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, я, лично, был бы против возвращения награды, но если такое делать, то нужен чёткий алгоритм и регламент модераторских действий (если что). Я не думаю, что всё так просто. Случаи могут быть не столь очевидные. Можно дать ответ, который не решает проблему, но который, тем не менее может получить несколько плюсов. принять его, получить награду обратно, потом, опять же, снять галку с ответа, удалить его, под предлогом "я всё переосмыслил" и снова бесплатно назначать конкурс.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Тоже не согласен, награда - это оплата "рекламы" вопроса. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276494/if-a-bounty-question-is-not-answered-solved-why-is-amount-not-returned-to-asker

Comment: @i-one , HolyBlackCat - а смысл отбирать награду у человека, если на вопрос не ответили, и к тому же он сам на него ответил?  Получается, что человек теряет репутацию не зависимо от исхода решения собственной задачи. По факту ему проще тогда уж ему и ответ на свой же вопрос не давать...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, да, я бы не назвал это "рекламой" в чистом виде, т.к. тогда награда должна была бы изыматься в пользу рекламной площадки (т.е. в данном случае просто изыматься), а не отвечающих (но чем их тогда заинтересовать?). И в то же время, это и не "наём специалиста", т.к. при наёме, если никто не нанялся, награда должна оставаться при вас. Что-то среднее между рекламой, тендером и наёмом. Худо-бедно (а на мой взгляд нормально), но это как-то работает. И, заметьте, без необходимости модераторского участия.

Comment: А можно как-то увидеть, насколько изменилась репутация? Кроме как косвенно подсчитать по числу вопросов. Чисто ради интереса... Было бы неплохо, чтобы это было видно, а то врятли кто-то пишет логи своей репутации, и многие этого просто и не заметят...

Comment: @zcorvid насколько я знаю, нет. Разве что, можно посмотреть свой профиль через вебархив до этого изменения и сравнить. Ну или в SEDE запрос написать.

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337843/154101

Comment: @VladD хорошо бы пояснение какое-то. То, что с сообществом никто не посоветовался перед этим решением - мы и так все знаем (:

Comment: @Suvitruf: Sapienti sat. А что, кто-то на нашей Мете явно сказал вслух, что с сообществом не посоветовались? (inb4: Нет, потому что это на нашем подсайте секрет Полишинеля.)

Comment: @VladD я не понимаю, что вы хотите донести, если честно. Да, с сообществом не советовались, это не секрет. И?

Comment: @Suvitruf: Тут есть многое: и политика администрации, и отношение к ней сообщества, и отношение к ней англоязычных модераторов, отношение к этому всему нашего сообщества, и многое другое, полный комплект, информация к размышлению на все вкусы. Но я не хочу давать свою оценку, пусть каждый, кто прочитает и сравнит, вынесет её для себя сам.

Comment: @VladD вы можете это отдельным вопросом задать, если хотите обсудить ситуацию с сообществом. Никто вам не мешает. Но вы ведь не будете, верно?

Comment: @Suvitruf: Не-а, не буду, и вы прекрасно знаете, почему.

Answer (score 10):

Это решение - антипаттерн проектирования сайта. По двум причинам. Первая - репутация как сравнительная характеристика членов сообщества стала намного менее информативна. Вторая причина - равенство ученика и учителя делает менее привлекательным труд учителя.
Всё вместе приведёт имхо к стагнации сайта, большему времени ожидания ответа, и более низкому качеству ответов.
Теперь подробнее:

**Репутация** - это по сути движитель стэкаоверфлоу и других вопросо-отвечательных сайтов. Хорошо спроектированная репутация должна отличать высококвалифицированного специалиста от школьника. А значит, пришедший на стэк профи должен в единицу времени набирать репы намного больше, чем студент.

Исследования о программистах на стэковерфлоу выявляли значительные корреляции некоторых величин с репутацией. Так [в исследовании 2015 года стэка](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2015#work-compensation-so) была найдена корреляция, которая говорила, что люди с репой более 10 000 очков зарабатывают на 35% больше. Теперь, искать зависимости между репутацией, зарплатой и  пользой для сайта становится бессмысленным.

Возможно со мной кто-то поспорит, но обществу нужны какие-то шкалы оценки программистов. Вклад на гитхабе - не всегда информативен. Иван может делать 20 плохих коммитов, а Пётр 2 хороших. Раньше можно было померится репутацией. Теперь в этом не осталось смысла -   любопытный школьник может за месяц набрать больше очков, чем профи со стажем.

С потерей значимости репутации, становится менее интересным процесс борьбы за неё. Какой смысл завтра майнить биткойны, если все будут их считать фуфлом? В [вышеупомянутом исследовании](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2015#community-answer) у людей спросили, "почему вы отвечаете?". Двадцать процентов сказали, цитирую:

> Demonstrating my expertise will benefit me.

Перевожу на русский - как минимум двадцать процентов (многие постеснялись признаться) отвечают ради выгоды. А репутация вполне себе была похожа на меру престижа в сообществе.

**Уравнение ученика и учителя**. В основе обучения нейросетей лежат стимулы. Нейросеть должна получать вознаграждение за хорошее поведение и наказываться за плохое. Правильный подбор стимулов - главная задача обучения нейросети.

Рассматривая сообщество как огромную нейросеть, мы в сущности, стремимся к расширению базы знаний. Начнём не правильно применять стимулы - рост базы снизится. Но база знаний - это побочный продукт, который возникает после ответа на одну сиюминутную потребность. В свою очередь потребность возникает так:

1. Мы пишем код.
2. Появляется чёртова ошибка из-за которой всё не пашет. Ошибку не получается пофиксить три часа, все коллеги с которыми есть связь, не смогли ни чем помочь.
3. Поплакав с полчаса, мы заходим на стэк, излагаем свою беду, сморкаясь в распечатку кода, отчётливо понимая, что если не помогут здесь, завтра нужно идти с заявлением по собственному желанию к начальнику.
4. Мы задаём вопрос, через минуту типичная Моника <s>Хулио</s> Чиллио отвечает нам, о том, что нужно инвертировать флаг переноса.
5. В следующую минуту мы инвертируем проклятый флаг и облегчённо вздыхаем. Мы вытираем сопли с распечатки кода, наш проект работает и идём мы домой с твёрдой уверенностью что начальство выплатит и месячную зарплату и квартальную премию.
6. Утром показывая начальству результат отладки, мы про себя поём: "Господи благослови коммиты святой Моники, защити её код от [гейзенбагов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3), помоги ей потоки с первого раза корректно синхронизировааать".
7. После тестов кода, мы обязательно плюсанём ещё одно сообщение, потому как в глубине души понимаем, что +20 слишком мало за такую сурьёзную помощь.

Подытоживая скажу по личному опыту. **Всякий человек которому правильно ответили на тяжёлый вопрос испытывает многосоставное счастье. От силы 3% этого счастья составляет плюсы к репутации на стэке.** Главное счастье от полученного ответа, то что я:

1. Решил проблему и меня не уволят.
2. Вырос как специалист.
3. Потерял чувство беспомощности, одиночества и собственной бесполезности для социума.
4. Сэкономил кучу времени и не стал заново перечитывать всю документацию в over 9000 страниц.

**Неужели всех этих плюшек кому-то из задающих вопросы не достаточно и обязательно нужно выдавать на пять очков больше?**

Лично я, даже в отсутствии стимулов, всё равно стал бы задавать нормальные вопросы. Желающих переложить свои проблемы на других, во все времена будет хотя отбавляй. А вот насчёт того, что интеллектуалы и квалифицированные специалисты будут всегда тусоваться на стэке у меня большие сомнения.

**Текущей мерой админы стэка уравняли в значимости отдающих и берущих. Провели эквивалент между хеллоувордщиками и сеньор девелоперами. Установили биекцию между обученной и не обученной нейросетью.**

Подобная мера отдаёт коммунизмом. А все коммунистические режимы грохнулись, в первую очередь от того, что снизили эффективность стимулов к труду. Коммунисты оттолкнули квалифицированных специалистов из-за чего оные стали интенсивно мигрировать в капиталистические страны, где было больше стимулов вознаграждения за хороший результат. Рецидив такой стагнации мы увидим на стэковерфлоу спустя считанные месяцы.

Ещё раз, те из нас, кто сегодня обрадовались лишней тысяче балов завтра станут пострадавшими от массового исхода квалифицированных специалистов. Те, кто получил сегодня +50% к репе, завтра получат +200% к времени ожидания ответа и -50% к качеству ответов.

Нет конечно, от этой меры стэк не развалится - сотни миллионов страниц контента будут посещаемы ещё ближайшие двадцать лет. Но может резко просесть процесс создания нового контента.

**PS.** От себя добавлю, что мне и раньше казалось, что двукратного разрыва не достаточно, чтобы отличать нуба от профи. Сейчас мне просто стыдно за лишние 850 очков (+60%) перед теми, кто помог мне.

Comment: С тем, что у отвечающего фактическая "награда" меньше, чем у вопрошающего, согласен. Но, с другой стороны, репутация имеет смысл лишь до определённого порога, чтобы по-нормальному пользоваться сайтом (у кого-то 3K, у кого-то 10 — зависит от желания заботиться о других). Дальше, как по мне, наступает спокойствие сенбернара — ну есть репутация, и есть. Что же насчёт отъёма мотивации уравниловкой — лично я отвечаю на нетривиальные вопросы, которые на поверхности простые, но если приглядеться, заставляют задуматься.

Comment: Причём описываемая проблема должна иметь все шансы встретиться у любого, кто случайно копнёт в её сторону. То есть награда — это возможность поразмять мозг, ну и попутно поделиться опытом и граблями. Если же подобных вопросов не видно, — не проблема, жизнь, задачи и способы провести свободное время есть и за пределами SO в частности, и интернета в общем.

Comment: Репутация обесценена. На большом SO у меня 8К репутации — фарм документации, ещё 8К — удвоенная репа за вопросы. И в сумме от моих 30К остаётся один пшик, которым гордиться сложно.

Comment: Откуда у вас столько ненависти к задающим вопросы? Вы так легко раздаете эпитеты типа "попрошайка" - но ведь вы сами задали больше вопросов, чем ответов. Почему вы считаете, что достойны помощи, а другие задающие вопросы - нет (они ж попрошайки!). К тому же все это "уравняние попрошаек с сеньерами" и прочее легко перечеркивается тем фактом, что за вопросы голосуют реже и меньше, чем за ответы. Набрать сколь-либо значимое количество репутации на вопросах настолько нереально, что за все это время на ruSO это смог сделать один участник.

Comment: @Kyubey, значит пора вырасти и перестать гордиться какими-то циферками.

Comment: @PashaPash эпитеты с себя списывал, это же самоочевидно. Нет никакой (само)ненависти. Я нигде не писал, что кто-то (попрошайки) не достоин помощи. Вы абсолютно верно пишите, что за правильные ответы сообщество голосует интенсивнее, чем за вопросы - да это от того, что все мы интуитивно понимаем, что авторов ответов нужно вознаграждать, относительно авторов вопросов в коэффициенте 1 к 10.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin ,не "мы все", а лично вы так считаете. Если вы процесс задачи вопроса ассоциируете с "попрошайничеством" - мне очень жаль. На самом деле сайт сейчас страдает от недостатка вопросов (и тем более хороших вопросов) намного сильнее, чем от недостатка ответов. Потому что чтобы ответить на средний вопрос, не нужно быть сверхсеньером. Достаточно знать чуть больше, чем автор вопроса. Что, учитывая что вопросы задают в основном новички-одиночки, достаточно легко. А вот задать хороший вопрос - очень тяжело. Поэтому медиана голосов за вопрос - 0.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin все достаточно просто. Чтобы отвечающим не было скучно, и чтобы они не поубегали, нужны хорошие вопросы. Хороший вопрос задать с первого раза тяжело. Поэтому докинули репутации, чтобы голоса за первый же хороший вопрос сильнее толкали автора задать следующий. Теперь со стартового новичкового вопроса человек получит 12 репутации. Раньше получал 7. Отвечающий обычно получал от 25. В два раза больше морковки, в два раза больше мотивации. А все это "попрошайничество" и прочая борьба с собой перед оформлением - вы просто интроверт. Бывает.

Comment: @PashaPash я нигде не писал, что процесс задавания вопроса = попрошайничество. Просто часть вопросов, 30-50% в моём видении, действительно являются креативом попрошаек.

Comment: @PashaPash я глянул в ваш профиль, у меня право вызывает большое уважение, такое количество отвеченных вопросов. Но поймите одну, простую вещь - не все отвечальщики, такие же как вы, готовы просто помогать, чтобы помогать. И если завтра от этого решения мы потеряем даже 25%, это очень негативно скажется на времени ожидания. Лично вы можете завтра заняться другими делами, к примеру байдарками или автогонками, и вам будет не до проблемных программеров со SO. А новые отвечальщики могут не придти из за этого. 
А лично на моей активности задавать вопросы, доброс репы никак не скажется.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, не понятно на чем основано ваше убеждение, что "отвечальщики" куда-то уйдут. Из зависти к тем кто задает вопросы что ли? Я считаю, что ничего глобально не изменится. Активные участники (и задающие вопросы, и отвечающие) как были, так и останутся, просто у тех кто регулярно задает вопросы будут иметь больше репутации. И то только те из них, кто задавал качественные вопросы.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin я не понимаю, как лишние 5-10 баллов за типовой вопрос вызовут уход "даже 25%" отвечающих. Вы рисуете какую-то нереальную картину - якобы, люди сидят на SO *исключительно* ради очков репутации, и только начисление этой самой репутации удерживает людей от ухода. На самом деле почти все сидят тут ради дофамина, который дает помощь людям (особенно в виде передачи своих знаний другим людям). Ведь участники активно правят чужие сообщения, гребут очереди проверки, на мете общаются - и никакой репутации за это не дают.

Comment: @PashaPash не сидят. Некоторые приходят чтобы заработать пару тысяч. Поднялись в своих глазах - и давай до свидания.  Я в посте показал исследование SO, что 20% - ради benefita сидят. Может и больше.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Ну а те, кто приходит чтобы заработать пару тысяч - таких еденицы, и они в любом случае уйдут, после зарабатывания этой пары тысяч, вне зависимости от того, сколько получают авторы вопросов. Даже наоборот, т.к. "репутация обесценена" - они будут оставаться дольше, ведь им теперь нужно будет заработать на пару тысяч больше, чтобы достичь порога ухода )

Comment: @AndrewKachalin "Demonstrating my expertise will benefit me" - это даже не близко "я тут ради бенефита в виде баллов репутации". Там в статье нет вообще ни одного пункта про репутации, и отлично видно, что основная мотивация - "It feels good to help a programmer in need" и "My answer will help lots of people who have the same problem in the future". Вы как-то вывели из "20% считают, что демонстрация своих умений - это **одна из причин**, по которой они сидят на SO" - "минимум 25% уйдут из-за +5 отвечающим, т.к. **только ценность репутации из тут удерживает**". Я не понимаю, откуда такой вывод.

Comment: @PashaPash я вижу у вас много мыслей по этому поводу. А мне не хочется устраивать спор из-за трактовок исследования. Может дадите развёрнутый ответ, со статистикой (то есть минимально научно обосновать) что будет лучше чем было. Может действительно, у вас есть пруфлинки того, что где-то подобная мера делалась на другом сайте и ничего плохого не произошло.  А я, честное слово, уже сказал выше всё и добавить мне нечего.

Comment: @PashaPash ну в самом деле. Давайте на минуту допустим, что "репутация для отвечальщиков вообще не является причиной, побуждающей дать ответ". Тогда отменив репутацию с сайта, теоретически, не должна снижаться активность, по крайней мере, ответов. Вы с этим согласны? А если не согласны, вот прикиньте, с 1 декабря отменили всю репу. Насколько просядет интенсивность ответов (если допустить что количество вопросов останется прежним). Просто дайте мне вашу, экспертную цифру.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin зависит от того, как введут изменение. Если просто возьмут и уберут репутацию - просядет на половину, в основном из-за возмущения "нас не спросили". Если перед этим будут готовить сообщество, придумают какую-то реальную причину, почему без репутации лучше, введут стандартную для форумов замену типа "количества постов" - просядет на 20-25%, но без геймефикации тяжело будет добирать новых отвечающих. Т.е. да, просядет, да, система репутации важна. Но уж точно не просядет на 25% из-за лишней пятерки задающим вопрос :)

Comment: @AndrewKachalin давайте я по-другому сформулирую - сама идея, что люди массово перестанут отвечать из-за того, что за хороший ответ им теперь станет прилетать всего в два раза больше репутации, чем за хороший вопрос (vs в 3 раза, как было раньше) - это достаточно странно, и немного обидно, что вы вообще такое предполагаете. Легко же проверить - хоть кто-то из участников заявил "это возмутительно, я больше не буду давать ответы этим попрошайкам!". Я не видел - ни на мете, ни в чате.

Comment: @PashaPash ну вот мы уже к какому-то консенсусу приходим. Убери репутацию -> в любом случае просядет количество ответов. Просто наши взгляды отличаются в количественном плане. Разумеется никто не напишит "я не буду больше помогать, раз такое отношение". Просто народ на мой взгляд, снизит активность, только-то и всего. А количественные взгляды снижения активности у нас с вами расходятся, и это нормально. А снизит активность народ -> дальше всё покатится как снежный ком.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin наши взгляды отличаются в качественном плане. я не считаю задающих вопросы попрошайками, и не считаю, что репутация является основной движущей силой (по опросу же хорошо видно. А в количественном - сайту не хватает именно вопросов. Если в результате изменений станет больше хороших задающих - эффект будет обратным. Реальное снижение активности будет только если кто-то на мете будет активно убеждать других участников, что теперь нет смысла отвечать, т.к. "админы стэка уровняли в значимости дарителей и попрошаек" - чем вы, собственно, и занимаетесь :)

Comment: Начав читать сообщение, поставил ему плюс. Дочитав, вынужден был отменить решение. Обязательно нужно было скатываться в политику?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в наше время без политики не куда. К примеру, в древней Греции, людей, которые не хотели принимать участие в политической жизни родного города называли "идиотами". Потому как считали, что человек самоустраняется от влияния на события только в силу слабоумия.

Comment: @all: Для того, чтобы были хорошие вопросы, нужно сделать так, чтобы на сайте было побольше хороших ответов. А для этого нужно, чтобы на сайте было побольше хороших отвечающих. Другого пути нет.

Answer (score 5):

Конечно, приятно вдруг получить существенное повышение репутации.
Сразу хочется вкладываться в этот ресурс.
А ведь совем недавно не хотелось…

И тут у меня возникает отчетливое ощущение, что всем участникам дали взятку. Репой, которая вообще-то и денег не стоит. И как-то уже и про Монику не вспоминают. Проехали. Это называется **геймификация**.
Отдельно отмечу, что автор идеи, возможно, не имела ввиду ничего такого. Просто именно сейчас начальство одобрило эту инициативу.

Comment: Инициатива задолго до ситуации с Моникой родилась.

Comment: "всем участникам дали взятку" - слишком сильно сказано: у многих вообще нет вопросов, или их немного, или нет вопросов с положительным рейтингом. У меня всего два вопроса, у обоих рейтинг +2, дельта репутации +20.

Comment: Нет не взятку. Просто отвлекли внимание. Понятно, что такое решение вызовет шквал эмоций. А руководству стэка выгоднее, чтобы обсуждали бред с репой, чем Монику.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, да ладно, вы думаете что администрация SO настолько идиоты, что считает нас такими идиотами, и думают что это кого-то отвлечет? Хватит притягивать одно к другому за уши. Это два абсолютно несвязанных события.

Comment: @insolor: Исходя из их излюбленного метода работы с проблемами (отмалчиваться и ничего не менять, считать мнение сообщества несущественным) — да, настолько.

Answer (score 5):

> Мы верим, что и авторы вопросов, и отвечающие — важные части нашей
>   экосистемы.

Вера тут непричем, это есть факт, я бы сказал, что они явлются единственными составляющими, привлекающим пользователей. Может быть для некоторых пользователей и очень важна репутация, но я не понимаю почему задающий вопрос вообше должен ожидать какие то  улучшения в репутации. Лично для меня, как задающего вопрос, важно:

1. Решить свою проблему, или
2. Поделиться интересующим мне вопросом с другими пользовательями, или
3. Узнать что то новое, узнать мнение профи по данному вопросу, или, даже, может
4. Поднять активность вопросов на сайте в некотором низкоактивном
       промежутке, просто придумывая вопрос...

Я лишь хочу сказать, что задающий вопрос уже имеет некоторую обьективную или субьективную выгоду. По положительным или отрицательным отзывам, он (другой участник) может оценить качество своего вопроса, и тем самым эти отзывы являются дополнительной помощью помимо ответов и комментарий.

Вознаграждение за вопрос в качестве репутаций, мне думается, нужно давать только тем, чей вопрос имеет несколько положительных отзывов(например начиная с пяти плюсов). Может быть количество  репутаций в таком случаи стоит и увеличить до `20` за каждый последующий голос, но суть в том, что вопрос, получивший много плюсов, является ценным вопросом как для сайта, так и для пользователей. Нынче получается, что начинающий задал 10 вопросов, ответы на которых знает каждый программист и хороший студент, и десять начинающих посчитали ваш вопрос полезным, в сумме получаете `100` баллов репутации, а человек, задающий один вопрос, действительно полезный для многих пользователей, может даже не набрать столько репутации. И хотя, для себя я не считаю репутацию стимулом для своего участия, но, думаю, еще раз нужно подумать по поводу данной темы обсуждения...

---

Что касается отвечающим, то они проделывают гораздо больше работу, чем задающие, их гораздо меньше, и к ним требования гораздо больше, потому что  качество ответа  намного важнее качества вопроса, и отвечающим, чаще(но не всегда так), нужно иметь гораздо больше
информации или опыта. Я понимаю, когда школьникам интересна набранная репутация.. Не думаю, что это важна для профи со стажем, но всеравно важно правильная политика вознаграждений. **Надеюсь,  многие понимают, что главным результатом ответов и вопросов является рост наших знаний, культуры общения и подачи информации.**  Я также надеюсь, что многие понимают, что далеко не всегда отвечающий обладает большими знаниями по отношению к задающему, поэтому нет тут никаких `учеников и учителей`,  а есть пользователи, имеющими затруднения и пользователи, знающие ответ на данный вопрос. Никто не может знать и помнить или замечать все...

Answer (score 2):

Мне всё равно.

1. Очки это очки, которые к действительности отношения почти не имеют.
2. Отвечать ради "пощрений", ну да, возможно, только возьмём к примеру Meta, здесь за вопросы/ответы голоса не начисляются. И теме не менее есть и те и другие.
3. Тут вот переживают по поводу "уравнивания" и что "школота" может набрать больше очков за счёт большего количества вопросов, ну так задавайте сами, в чём вопрос? К тому же, если такие пользователи переусердствуют, то за большое количество некачественных вопросов они могут ещё себе и неприятностей нажить в виду различных ограничений при пользовании RUSO.
4. Для подтверждения же своего уровня образованности куда полезнее и выгоднее вкладывать силы, время и знания в свои разработки, по примеру того же Игоря Сысоева, nginx-ом которого пользуются многие из нас.
5. Сейчас RUSO есть, а завтра его нет. И всё. Ваши время, записи, усилия в трубу (не совсем конечно же, во время написания ответов/вопросов тоже происходит обучение), а свои разработки — нет. К слову, помимо разработок можно писать книги, что тоже даёт и поощрение, и поднимает самооценку, а также дополнительный доход.
6. RUSO хорош как эдакий общественный рабочий дневник заметок, не более, по моему скромному мнению.

Answer (score 1):

Я против данного нововведения т.к:

- Ответы действительно дороже вопросов.
- Репутация должна быть показателем.
- И главное: **закон не имеет обратной силы**.

Если так необходимо данное нововведение ,тo возможно стоит старую репутацию **не пересчитывать**.

Comment: "Ответы действительно дороже вопросов" - это не само собой разумеется. "Репутация должна быть показателем" - показателем чего?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что репутация должна показывать квалифицированность как программиста(ну а также как давно человек на сайте :))."Ответы дороже вопросов " — обсуждалось выше.

Comment: Никогда не задумывались, что без хороших вопросов не появятся хорошие ответы?

Comment: А без хороших ответов нет смысла задавать хорошие вопросы.