# Опечатка в тексте объявления

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, уведомления

В тексте объявления

> Мы вознаграждаем авторов вопросов пересчитав репутацию! Подробнее.

допущена ошибка - нет обозначения деепричастного оборота.

Но по моему мнению, лучше придерживаться дословного перевода основного объявления

> We’re rewarding the question askers & reputations are being recalculated! Read more.

Перевод

> Мы вознаграждаем задающих вопросы, репутация будет пересчитана! Подробнее.

Comment: День добрый. 1. Такое лучше в самом [объявлении писать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9753/15479) в комментариях. Или в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). 2. Не нужно дословно всё переводить. ^_^

Comment: Так я не спорю по поводу перевода, а обозначаю пунктуационную ошибку. @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, русский язык еще не отменили?

Comment: Но в "Мы вознаграждаем авторов вопросов пересчитав репутацию! Подробнее." нету деепричастного оборота.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, остановитесь.

Comment: Если вы уверены, что в сообщении ошибка, то вы можете [поправить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) текст сами. В этом суть сообщества.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica "пересчитав репутацию" - деепричастный оборот. "Подъезжая к сией станцыи и глядя на природу в окно, у меня слетела шляпа."

Comment: @Igor ага. Я что-то про совершенный вид деепричастий совсем позабыл =/

Comment: Согласен с тем, что "Мы вознаграждаем авторов вопросов" звучит понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Я вообще сначала подумал, что речь про [этот пост](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9753/15479) ^_^"

И только сейчас осознал, что речь про уведомление вверху страницы. Я попросил Адама поправить текст (и заодно ссылку на наш перевод вместо ссылки на запись в блоге).

Comment: Отличная идея !

Comment: А теперь попроси вернуть как было)

Comment: @Qwertiy остановитесь D:

Comment: В комментарии выше ☝ опять запятую пропустили! Остановитесь!

Answer (score -1):

## Эта запятая ЛИШНЯЯ и надо её убрать

> Также не нужны запятые, если деепричастие выражает не дополнительное действие, а оттенок основного

<sup>Источник: http://ktvd.ru/obosoblenie-deeprichastnych-oborotov/</sup>

> **Примечание.** Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:
>
> 1) если деепричастный оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания: *Она сидела чуть откинув голову* (Марк.) — указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела с откинутой головой; *Жили Артамоновы ни с кем не знакомясь* (М. Г.) — важно, что жили без всяких знакомств; *Это упражнение делают* ***стоя на вытянутых носках*** — смысл сообщения в том, каким образом делают упражнение; *Старик шёл* ***прихрамывая на правую ногу**;* *Студенты приобретают знания* ***не только слушая лекции, но и выполняя практические работы**;* *Писал он обычно* ***наклонив голову**;* ***Не унижая себя*** *говорю, а говорю с болью в сердце* (М. Г.); *Огромного роста, редкой силы, волосатый, он ходил по земле* ***наклоня голову,*** *как бык* (М. Г.); *Яков сидел* ***опустив ноги*** (М. Г.).

<sup>Источник: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113</sup>

Comment: Если "Мы вознаграждаем авторов вопросов пересчитывая репутацию", то, возможно это правило и сработает. Не очень понимаю напряжения по поводу запятой.

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/20805/4076

Comment: @contributorpw 1. Я выбрал другое правило из второго источника. 2. А почему ты задал вопрос на сайте, где пользователи не русскоязычные?