# Чем объясняется получение репутации в последние дни?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, репутация

Всем привет. Я сегодня получил неожиданное "пополнение" и задался вопросом - откуда? Набрёл на [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9753/%D0%9C%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) на мете, там вроде как написано что прилетит репа и много кто её получит. Но я решил всё-таки задать этот вопрос, так как я приверженец справедливого начисления баллов и не хочу, чтобы кто-то (например я) получил баллы халявно.

Если мое пополнение объясняется пересчётом то всё нормально, но может произошёл глюк какой-то? Есть второй вариант, он менее вероятен, но я его тоже допускаю - в виду своего "преклонного" возраста я забыл сколько у меня баллов было, но этого не может быть. Если у кого-то есть доступ к нужной информации, то я буду рад, если объясните мне суть. Заранее спасибо за ответы и любую полезную информацию.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всё верно. [Изменили начисляемую репутацию за вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9753/15479). Это касается как всех старых вопросов, так и всех новых.

Так что, не баг ^_^

Comment: фух,вы меня успокоили)) спасибо большое))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko рад был помочь ^_^