# Что делать, если рейтинг на сайте ОЧЕНЬ сильно упал?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, голоса-против, качество-вопроса

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, что делать, если мой рейтинг упал настолько сильно, что не могу даже ответить на собственный вопрос?

Был рейтинг нормальный. После задал несколько вопросов, получил ответ в комментарии, несколько негативных оценок. Как бы ничего, но со временем их накопилось очень много. А если новый вопрос задают через минут так 5 первый негативная оценка уже стоит.

Не знаю в большинстве случаев причину; а если пишут в комментариях "исправь", "не понятен вопрос" и т.д, я не знаю, что исправлять, поскольку ответ дан был в комментариях, и ему было понятно, я даже иногда благодарю.

Comment: Может вы просто перепутали аккаунт? Вашему аккаунту всего месяц, активность тоже не большая, не думаю, что на нем когда-то был высокий рейтинг.

Comment: @RTK был 20, после всё в пропасть...

Comment: Ну так на вкладке активности в профиле наглядно указано, куда эти все 20 улетели

Comment: 20? Очень сильно упал? Серьёзно?

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну как бы он упал настолько что я даже на собственный вопрос ответить не могу ._.

Comment: У вас нет блокировки вопросов, можете спрашивать, у вас блокирована возможность давать ответы. Только давайте попробуем понять, что вторично, а что первично: первично то, что ответы некачественные, вторично то, что из-за этого их минусуют (рейтинг снижается) и итог то, что если постоянно публиковать некачественные ответы система автоматически блокирует возможность давать ответы.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Это вам легко потерять, а для новичков это стихийное бедствие.

Comment: Дополню слова @AK: блокировка возможности давать ответы временная. Некоторое количество плюсов на вопросах (неизвестно какое) снимает эту блокировку.

Comment: @AK У его ответов рейтинг +0/-0. Если запрет именно на ответы самому себе, дело в вопросах.

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica ну и я был новичком 3 года назад. Тем не менее даже тогда 20 баллов репутации не были проблемой. Ведь это всего два плюса или два принятых ответа.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Ну кому как, новички бывают разные. Кто-то может нормально общаться с людьми и уметь задавать поставленные вопросы, а кто-то может передавать информацию только через "ПАМАГИТЕ НЕ МОГУ РЕШИТЬ".

Comment: Попутно переписал ваш вопрос «[Программа работает некоректно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1049825/208074)»  — можете на его примере посмотреть, как правильно структурировать вопросы. Грамматические ошибки — это мелочи (мы тоже на английском не ахти как пишем), самое главное — структура (*код — как задумано — как получилось — в чём, собственно, вопрос*).

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev, благодарю, надеюсь я понял структуру.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как уже писали в комментариях:

1. Важны причины. Почему упал рейтинг? Потому что что-то не так с вопросом.
2. Как поправить?

   - Отредактировать прошлые сообщения, основываясь на фидбеке участников.
   - Наученным опытом задавать новые вопросы с учётом прошлых ошибок.
3. [За 1 голос "за" на вопросе теперь дают `10` репутации, а не `5`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9753/15479).

Т.е, первое, что нужно сделать - понять, в чём проблема с вопросами и как их исправить. А репутация придёт естественным путём, если с вопросами будет всё в порядке.

Есть нюансы, естественно:

- Что делать, если не понятно, что не так с вопросом? Можно попросить совета в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).
- Бывает так, что вопрос в целом неплох, но подан так, что участникам не понравилось. Такое часто бывает, когда участники воспринимают вопрос, как "домашку". В таких случаях обычно хватает просто добавления информации в вопрос про ваши попытки решить оный.

Answer (score 9):

@Witalik, я видел ваши вопросы. Проблемы с вашими вопросами такие:

1. Вопросы односложные и короткие.
2. Часто отсутствует форматирование кода.
3. Много грамматических ошибок.

Классический [пример вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1049545/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-if-%d0%b8-switch)

По сути сквозит неуважение к человеку, который будет отвечать. Нужно формулировать вопросы более чёткие и понятные (если вам самим понятен вопрос, это не означает, что он будет понятен другому). Советы:

- Не торопитесь, когда пишете вопрос.
- Чётко формулируйте вопрос.
- Объясните контекст вопроса, уместно иногда и привести пример.
- Соблюдайте форматирование кода.
- Сделайте пруфридинг текста, в сети всегда много ресурсов, которые позволяют исправить грамматические ошибки.

Comment: Не всегда ясен сам вопрос и не знаю как его расписать, именно по этому приходитса писать вопрос односложным.

Ну примеры буду приводить по меры возможности.

Нуу я стараюсь только не всегда получаетса, у каждого свой вкусс так сказать, я стараюсь быть по-средине.

Преведите примеры сайтов которые позволят исправить ошибки.